# What is the physics behind a TV wall mount?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, statics

As I was installing this [wall mount](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SHFPD8S), I began to wonder how exactly physics is at work with it. In other words, how does the design of the mount play a role in ensuring that the mount itself supports the television/device and distributes the forces at play? I have seen different types of wall mounts ([like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SGD4TB4)). Does the shape or structure of the mount make one much stronger (more efficient at distributing the forces) than another? Outside of allowing rotation does the swivel extension make the mount any better withstanding the forces? Thank you.

I'm not too sure if this question was/is better suited for the engineering stack exchanged but I came across this answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/437607/295975) and thought I would take a shot. If this is not appropriate feel free to move it (moderators) to where you believe it will fit best.  Thank you.

[Per suggestion, the question was asked (and answered) on the Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50629/32989).

Comment: More an Engineering question?

Comment: @Farcher I will ask the question on the Engineering Stack Exchange as well.

Comment: Perhaps this help you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437571/how-to-calculate-the-weight-of-a-tv-mounted-on-a-different-type-of-brackets-and

Answer (score 1):

From an engineering standpoint, you develop the mount in such a way that you would

1. Choose a maximum mass of television that the mount should support.
2. Determine what gravitational forces that mass entails, and any torques generated at distance $r$ from the wall to the mount point (more relevant for the extending arms).
3. Develop the mount in such a way that it ensures a static scenario at any position given a television which is under the maximum allowable mass.

Obviously this is more difficult for the extending style mount, as the mounting screws are subject to a torque, which grows larger the further the mass is from the wall. ($\tau=r \times F$)

Smart engineers would hopefully work from their chosen mass, design and choose materials in such a way that the maximum chosen mass can be exceeded by a reasonable amount. Ultimately though, the mounts which keep the TV close to the wall and have less overall range of motion should be easier to  design than the full range swivel/extension mounts, due to the torque created on the mounting screws at full extension distance.